# All pairs shortest path issue

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, adjacency-matrix, floyd-warshall

I've written this program that implements a graph with 100 nodes using an adjacency matrix. I've also used a Floyd-Warshall algorithm to find all pairs shortest path for all 100 nodes. Now, I'd like to condense the 100 x 100 matrix down to a 10 x 10 matrix that contains the all pairs shortest path only for the 10 indexes specified by `public static final int A = 100`...`public static final int W = 66`. How should I condense the array? I've begun construction of a new method called `arrayCondenser`, but is there a simpler way to do this?

```
public class AdjacencyMatrix
{       
    public static final int NUM_NODES = 100;
    public static final int INF = 99999;

    public static final int A = 20;
    public static final int B = 18;
    public static final int C = 47;
    public static final int D = 44;
    public static final int E = 53;
    public static final int F = 67;
    public static final int G = 95;
    public static final int H = 93;
    public static final int I = 88;
    public static final int W = 66;

    public static boolean even(int num) 
    {
        return num%2==0;
    }

    public static boolean odd(int num) 
    {
        return num%2==1;
    }

    public static void initialize(int [][] adjMat, int N) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j <N; j++)
                adjMat[i][j]=INF;

        for(int x = 0; x<N; x++)
        {
            int row = x/10;
            int column = x%10;

            if (even(row)) {
                if (column!=9)
                    adjMat[x][x+1]=1;
            }
            if (odd(row)) {
                if (column!=0)
                    adjMat[x][x-1]=1;
            }
            if (even(column)){
                if (row!=9)
                    adjMat[x][x+10]=1;
            }
            if (odd(column)) {
                if (row!=0)
                    adjMat[x][x-10]=1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static int[][] floydWarshall(int[][] adjMat, int N)
    {
        adjMat = new int[N][N];
        initialize(adjMat, N);

        for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k) 
        {
           for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
           {
              for(int j = 0; j < N; ++j) 
              {
                 adjMat[i][j] = Math.min(adjMat[i][j], adjMat[i][k] +   adjMat[k][j]);
              }
           }
        }

        return adjMat;
    }

    public static int[][] arrayCondenser(int[][] adjMat, int N)
    {
        int[] array = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,W};
        adjMat = floydWarshall(adjMat, N);




        return adjMat;
    }

    public static void printGrid(int[][] adjMat)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<NUM_NODES; ++i)
        {
           for (int j=0; j<NUM_NODES; ++j)
           {
               if (adjMat[i][j]==INF)
                   System.out.printf("%5s", "INF");
               else
                   System.out.printf("%5d",adjMat[i][j]);
           }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int adjMat[][] = new int[NUM_NODES][NUM_NODES];
        adjMat = floydWarshall(adjMat, NUM_NODES);

        printGrid(adjMat);            

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. The Floyd-Warshall algorithm considers iteratively (as you know) each shortest path using the previous vertices. Once you remove the vertices (and by proxy, edges) then you are removing the valid scenarios for shortest path which may or may not include those vertices.

Once you change which set of vertices you are using, you would have to recalculate the shortest paths for your new graph. Otherwise, you'd basically have to keep track of every single path so that when you removed vertices, you could remove any paths that used those vertices - and thereby have your new shortest paths.